# Transaction still listed as 'pending' after 12 hours

Tags: blockchain, electrum

I'm using Electrum 2.5.4 on Tails 2.2.1

Sent the following transaction over 12 hours ago with 0.0005 BTC/kB transaction fee.

There's a warning message saying the transaction has a none standard input - which after googling doesn't seem to have a concensus on what to do about this

What gives? Any help much appreciated

https://blockchain.info/tx/22e6190880cb2433fb99f27e7daf1a763c5e86d64fadb40b708be8295283a052

Answer (score 0):

The higher the number of unconfirmed transactions (in the mempool) the longer will take to confirm your transaction unless you give a higher fee.

I recommend watching [current mempool](https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/) where you can see the number of unconfirmed transactions and it gives you an idea how "clogged up" is the Bitcoin network.

Unconfirmed transaction will either confirm or expire (not sure but I think it takes 3 days to expire).

Comment: Would you be able to ELI5 the current mempool link you sent over in relation to my transaction? I was under the impression my fee was healthy (unchanged, default Electrum fee)

Comment: In the link you can currently see:

Comment: Sorry for the previous uncomplete comment.

In the link you can see:

20,982 tx 81,596.61 XBT
Total fees: 5.4042 XBT
Total size: 16.30 MB
Fee/size: 33.16 sat/B

Comment: Which means there are 20,982 uncofirmed transactions (normal is below 5000). I would recommend giving a higher fee than normal if there's > 10,000 unconfirmed transactions. On the page, blue column represents number of transactions and yellow column represents value in bitcoins. On the left are mined blocks (confirmed transactions) and on the right is the mempool (unconfirmed transactions).

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. The transaction has just been processed. I was specifically concerned about the 'none standard input' flag - but doesn't appear to have been the cause of the hold up as you have pointed out. Best regards